# What % of kohanim were not members of a mishmar?

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash

In the time of the Temple, kohanim were assigned to work in the Temple on a rotating, weekly basis.  The term for such a a crew was a mishmar.  But there were more kohanim than were needed. So some kohanim were not assigned to a mishmar.<sup>[1]</sup>  What percent of kohanim were members of a mishmar?  Also, the mishmarot were established by families.  What if a family grew so large that not all family members were needed to work in the Temple on one of the family's weeks?  Was there a special way to decide which kohanim in a family would serve, and was that determination permanent or could the mishmar consist of different family members over time (beyond replacements for unavoidable reasons, such as death)?

---

<sup>[1] Footnote 21 to daf 17a of Schottenstein edition of Taanis.</sup>